# shiny actionButton() hit the xth time runs code in observe() to run x times: callback of JS and DT::dataTableOutput

Tags: r, shiny

Im fairly new to shiny and Im observing a weird behaviour of an observeEvent block:
I am working on a shiny app for data analyis. At this point of the app, I want the user to select some subsets of the data and select which data to plot a scatter: x, y and color gradient.

In order to protect the code from plotting while things are not selected yet, I use an action button to define a string for subsetting. The data is composed of signals from different tissues and I want the user to select either one or some tissues.

Only after the actionButton is pressed, I want to bring up a DT with checkboxes. This table lists the data and the user can select which marker goes on x/y/colorgradient. I use for this purpose javascript callback, but I had problems with returning the Markerstring.
The callback only worked if you put it into an `observe()`, and only via a complicated `lapply(sapply(` combo that Im not proud of. In the observer, you then allow plotting only if all x/y/colorgradient are defined.

There is certainly a more elegant way to do that, but it worked like this as expected, **until I realized that for every click on the actionButton, the observer is triggered multiple times**.
There might be a very easy workaround to reset the actionButton counter, or it is the way I read from the JS callback. So any advice would be awsome. Im sorry that the MWE is long, I stripped it from everything unneccessary (plots and further subsettings..) but it is still rather complicated. Much appreciated if you take your time to dig through it..

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)      


ui <- fluidPage( 
 
 column(5,
        br(),
        h4("Code runs x times for x times that action button has been pressed"),

 p(style="text-align: justify;",
   "I plot a subset of a big dataframe, and the user has to choose three things: a subset of tissues, and then x y and a third column for color.
   To protect the code from plotting, I use an action button to define a string of tissue. This string is used to subset the dataframe via subset(data, Tissue %in% input)
    The code waits for this action button to be pressed:
         "), 

 DT::dataTableOutput('select.tissues.for.gatecheck'),
 actionButton("confirmTissuesToCheckGates", "Confirm and lock tissue(s)"), 
 br(),
 verbatimTextOutput('selected.tissue'),
 
 
 
 br(),
 br(),
 br(),
 
 p(style="text-align: justify;",
   "After the button is pressed, you get the list and you select three marker signals to plot a scatterplot. Plotting is only allowed if all three are selected. 
   This all works fine, but if you change the selection of Tissues and hit Confirm, the code starts running multiple times:
         "), 
 p(style="text-align: justify;",
   "You can most easily follow that behaviour on the console where the server plots three times", code("Not gonna do anything")," as you click the Confirm button and two of the three checkboxes. 
   The third checkbox then frees the code for plotting", code("Plotting now"),". If you then make a new tissue selection and de-select one marker, you see that the code runs through the observe braket already twice. Another new tissue selection causes it to run three tiems...I wonder what is causing that?
         "), 
 
 
 DT::dataTableOutput('select.scatterplot.markers.cell.dat') ,
 verbatimTextOutput('selected.scatterplot.marker.cols')

 
 )  #end column
)  #end ui fluidpage



server <- function(input, output, session) {

 # we store reactive values all in here:
 paths <- reactiveValues()
 
 
 
 # this is a long dataframe with signals and stuff. These signals are sorted by category:
 categories <- c("spleen", "pancreas", "liver"  )
 
 output$select.tissues.for.gatecheck = DT::renderDataTable( as.matrix( categories     ) , server = TRUE ,
                                                            options = list(pageLength = -1, 
                                                                           info = TRUE,
                                                                           lengthMenu = list( c(-1, 1), c("All", "1") ),
                                                                           columns = list( list(title =  "Tissue(s) available in data:"  ) )
                                                            ) 
 )
 

 
 marker.signals <- c("Marker1_signal", "Marker2_signal", "Marker3_signal", "Marker4_signal")
 
 
 
 m = matrix(
   as.character(1:3), nrow = length(marker.signals), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, 
   dimnames = list(marker.signals, c("1st marker (x)","2nd marker (y)","3rd marker (color gradient)") ) 
 )
 
 for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
   m[i, ] = sprintf(
     '<input type="checkbox" name="%s" value="%s"/>', # type: checkbox radio is not the way to go, it does not allow the user to deselect and return to the initial state...
     marker.signals[i], m[i, ]
   )
 }
 m
 
 
 
 
 output$select.scatterplot.markers.cell.dat = DT::renderDataTable(
   m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
   options = list(dom = 't', 
                  paging = FALSE, 
                  ordering = FALSE#,
   ),
   callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
         var $this = $(this.node());
         $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
         $this.addClass('shiny-input-checkboxgroup'); 
       });
       Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
       Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
 )
 
 
 # we fill the text box with a pre-selection text:
 output$selected.tissue = renderPrint({
   cat('No tissue(s) are selected:\n\n')
   cat( "waiting for confirmation")
   
   #}
 })
 
 
 
 observeEvent(input$confirmTissuesToCheckGates,  {
   
   # store the selection away since I need to do other things with the selection
     paths$do.something.with.selected.tissue <- categories[ input$select.tissues.for.gatecheck_rows_selected ]

     
   #...there is more irrelevant code here...  
     
     
   
   # report the subset of selected tissues as textbox:
   output$selected.tissue = renderPrint({
     cat( "Subsetting data with these tissues:\n\n"  )
     cat( isolate(paths$do.something.with.selected.tissue) , sep = ', ')
   })#end render print
   
   #after some plotting, I bring the variable back:  
   scatterplots.of.selected.tissue <- isolate( paths$scatterplots.of.selected.tissue )


   observe({
      # this is terrible way to get the marker string back out from the JS. 
     # 1 the sapply uses the input of the checkboxes and creates a list with NULL and characters 1, 2, 3 if the marker is checked
     # 2 this list is then scanned by lapply with a function ch that greps the element with the value 1, and returns it rather than a TRUE/FALSE statement
     # 3 from this checked element, we just take the name...
     # 4 there is a risk that during selecting-deselecting a marker for the plot axis, one variable (x/x/color) contains more than one element which would crash ggplot. so lets take only element [1] behind names to be sure
     capture.output(  cat( names(unlist(lapply(sapply(marker.signals, function(i) input[[i]]), function(ch) grep("1", ch, value = TRUE))))[1] ) ) -> paths$scatter.plot.x.marker
     capture.output(  cat( names(unlist(lapply(sapply(marker.signals, function(i) input[[i]]), function(ch) grep("2", ch, value = TRUE))))[1] ) ) -> paths$scatter.plot.y.marker
     capture.output(  cat( names(unlist(lapply(sapply(marker.signals, function(i) input[[i]]), function(ch) grep("3", ch, value = TRUE))))[1] ) ) -> paths$scatter.plot.color.marker
     
     
     # print the selected markers in the text field. I dont put that output inside the protected bracket that only executes once all three are checked, but I wanna have it update dynamically while clicking:
     # this render wont fail since the variables are pre-loaded with NULL and the paste0 wont fail if printing NULL
     output$selected.scatterplot.marker.cols =  renderPrint({
       
       cat( paste0("Direct axis marker: ", isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.x.marker) , 
                   "\nIndirect axis marker: ", isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.y.marker) ,
                   "\nColor gradient marker: ", isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.color.marker)
       ) )
     })#end textoutput of what is currently selected
     
     
     
     if( length( isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.color.marker) )==1 & length( isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.y.marker) )==1 & length( isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.x.marker) )==1 ){ 
       message("Plotting now")
     }else{
       message("Not gonna do anything")
     }
     
     
    
     
   })#end observe the JS callback
   

 }, ignoreInit = TRUE )# end observe "lock tissue(s)" button
}#end server


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

EDIT: I found a workaround without the actionButton. Simply putting the `rows_selected` inside the observer and protecting the code from running as long as this selection is not done:

```
   observe({
     paths$do.something.with.selected.tissue <- categories[ input$select.tissues.for.gatecheck_rows_selected ]
     

     if( length( isolate(  paths$do.something.with.selected.tissue )) ){
       
       # report the subset of selected tissues as textbox:
       output$selected.tissue = renderPrint({
         cat( "Subsetting data with these tissues:\n\n"  )
         cat( isolate(paths$do.something.with.selected.tissue) , sep = ', ')
       })#end render print

      # this is terrible way to get the marker string back out from the JS. 
     # 1 the sapply uses the input of the checkboxes and creates a list with NULL and characters 1, 2, 3 if the marker is checked
     # 2 this list is then scanned by lapply with a function ch that greps the element with the value 1, and returns it rather than a TRUE/FALSE statement
     # 3 from this checked element, we just take the name...
     # 4 there is a risk that during selecting-deselecting a marker for the plot axis, one variable (x/x/color) contains more than one element which would crash ggplot. so lets take only element [1] behind names to be sure
     capture.output(  cat( names(unlist(lapply(sapply(marker.signals, function(i) input[[i]]), function(ch) grep("1", ch, value = TRUE))))[1] ) ) -> paths$scatter.plot.x.marker
     capture.output(  cat( names(unlist(lapply(sapply(marker.signals, function(i) input[[i]]), function(ch) grep("2", ch, value = TRUE))))[1] ) ) -> paths$scatter.plot.y.marker
     capture.output(  cat( names(unlist(lapply(sapply(marker.signals, function(i) input[[i]]), function(ch) grep("3", ch, value = TRUE))))[1] ) ) -> paths$scatter.plot.color.marker
     
     
     if( length( isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.color.marker) )==1 & length( isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.y.marker) )==1 & length( isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.x.marker) )==1 ){ 
       message("Plotting now")
     }else{
       message("Not gonna do anything")
     }
     
     
     }#and if lenght action button
     
     
     # print the selected markers in the text field. I dont put that output inside the protected bracket that only executes once all three are checked, but I wanna have it update dynamically while clicking:
     # this render wont fail since the variables are pre-loaded with NULL and the paste0 wont fail if printing NULL
     output$selected.scatterplot.marker.cols =  renderPrint({
       
       cat( paste0("Direct axis marker: ", isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.x.marker) , 
                   "\nIndirect axis marker: ", isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.y.marker) ,
                   "\nColor gradient marker: ", isolate(  paths$scatter.plot.color.marker)
       ) )
     })#end textoutput of what is currently selected
     
     
     
   })#end observe the JS callback
```

Comment: You are nesting `observe({...})` inside a `observeEvent({...})`, and an `output$abc` inside that `observe({})`.  If you close your `observe`r just above the `output$$selected.scatterplot.marker.cols`, it does not display multiple messages.

Comment: that is not the problem: removing both `output$abc` still plots multiple messages. And: closing `observe` above `output$selected.scatterplot.marker.cols` (and keeping the `if`-`else` in that observer still produces multiple messages upon multiple clicking the action buttton.